# How to get a class from listbox datasource

Tags: asp.net, listbox, datasource

So I have the code code which binds the object class to a list box:

```
lstDealers.DataSource = dealers;
lstDealers.DataTextField = "DealerName";
lstDealers.DataBind();
```

This works fine, I have no problem displaying the values. However the problem I am having is I am trying to get the class from the list object.

I have tried two different methods but none have worked:

```
var selectedItems = from ListItem i in lstDealers.Items where i.Selected select i;
Dealer dealer = (Dealer)selectedItems;
```

and

```
Dealer dealer = (Dealer)lstDealers.SelectedItem;
```

Now I know the second one works in a winform, however I am trying to accomplish this in ASP.Net framework 4.5

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In web forms the `SelectedItem` does not have the object of type being assigned in `DataSource` rather you will get `ListItem`.

You have to use the current item to get the record from your data source as the `dealers` object is not available on *postback*. You can assign unique id to *DataValueField* which you will use after *postback* to fetch the record from *datasource* (database)

```
lstDealers.DataValueField = "IdOfDealer";
```

On postback

```
string dealerId = (Dealer)lstDealers.SelectedValue;    
Dealer dealer = someMethodToFetchAndReturnDealer(dealerId);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this then?